# Shifting down bits in MIPS for a floating point multiplication

Tags: assembly, mips, bit-shift

Say I had two significands stored in t2 and t3, and I wished to multiply them. I'd do so with:

```
 mult $t2, $t3
```

I'm multiplying two 24 bit numbers, so result is going to be 48 bits in total stored in the HI and LO registers. Now what I need to do is shift down the bits in the HI and LO registers so that a leading 1 present in bit position 48 is going to be shifted to bit position 24.

I'd appreciate any tips on how to deal with this problem ... I don't know how to code such a shift, especially since I have two different registers i'm dealing with.

Comment: Note that the leading 1 bit will not be in a fixed position. As for doing a shift across registers that's just some simple bit twiddling. You shift the low word right, then  the high word **left** so that you properly align for transferring into the low word, which you do with bitwise `or`.

Answer (score 0):

Reposting as an answer [Jester](https://stackoverflow.com/u/547981)'s comment:

> Note that the leading 1 bit will not be in a fixed position. As for doing a shift across registers that's just some simple bit twiddling. You shift the low word right, then the high word **left** so that you properly align for transferring into the low word, which you do with bitwise `or`. – Jester Apr 4 at 17:43